# Javascript img multiple .src for .onload

Tags: javascript

**Can I do this?**

```
(function (){function init(){
    var imgload = new Image();
    imgload.src = "/loading.gif";
imgload.onload = function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/background.jpg";
    img.src = "/logo.png";
    img.src = "/newtab.png";
img.onload = function(){setTimeout(function() {
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    html.style.background = "url('/background.jpg') center center fixed";
    html.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
    jQuery(".wrapper").fadeOut(400);
    jQuery(".loading").fadeOut(300);
    jQuery('.bodycontent').fadeIn(400)}, 300)}}}init()})();
```

I want to set multiple .src so then I could do .onload until the images in .src are loaded.

**Is this a good approach?**

Based on answers, here is how I did it:

```
function imgLoading(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      resolve(img);
    }
  });
}
let images =["/background.jpg","/logo.png","/submittrack.png", "/radio.png"];
var imgLoad = new Image();
imgLoad.src = "/loading.gif";
imgLoad.onload = function(){
    let imageLoadPromises = images.map(imgLoading);
    Promise.all(imageLoadPromises).then(function(images){
        setTimeout(function() {
            var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
            html.style.background = "url('/background.jpg') center center fixed";
            html.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
            jQuery(".wrapper").fadeOut(400);
            jQuery(".loading").fadeOut(300);
            jQuery('.bodycontent').fadeIn(400)}, 300)

    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a good approach

No. The src will be overwritten almost instantly and only the last url will get registered in the `onload`

---

You could use promises if you need to know when all of the images are loaded

```
let images =["/background.jpg","/logo.png","/newtab.png"];

function imgLoad(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      resolve(img);
    }
    img.onerror = reject
  });
}

// map an array of promises calling imgLoad() for each url
let imageLoadpromises = images.map(imgLoad);

Promise.all(imageLoadpromises ).then(function(images){
   //images is array of image elements from above
   // do something here , they have all loaded

}).catch(function(err){ 
     console.log('One or more images did not load')
});
```

Comment: There's a small typo after (imgLoad), missing a closing parenthesis `:-)`.

Comment: Intresting but I need img.onload to tell when all the images are loaded. I have a setTimeout function wrapped on img.onload. It works for one image but it doesn't work for multiple .src

Comment: The code inside `Promise.all.then` won't fire until they have **all** loaded and resolved each promise in the `onload` callbacks

Comment: So `init()` would be the Promise.all. All the code inside your `onload` would be put inside `Promise.all.then`

Comment: @charlietfl Look at my question. I added what I tried. I still get an error.

Comment: Basic code works https://jsfiddle.net/92aehmge/. Create  demo that displays the same error

Comment: OK...paths are no good in that demo so promises will never resolve

Comment: Obviously they're not good because they're local files. I can't add files to jsfiddle.

Comment: No but you can use valid images from somehwere...placeholder images, imagur ...anywhere

Comment: @charlietfl I did it. Check my question for the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are just updating the src of your `img` tag on your next line instead of adding multiple images. 
Here's an example that is just simulating what you are actually doing:

```
var a = 'Good Morning';
a = "Good Night";
a = "Good afternoon";
```

And here's a basic example of doing it the right way.

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "/newtab.png";
 img.onload = callMeOnLoad;

 var img2 = new Image();
 img2.src = "/background.jpg";
 img2.onload = callMeOnLoad;

 function callMeOnLoad(){
     //Stuff Here
 }
```

This isn't the ideal way either but just to explain the fact an `img` can take only 1 src.

@charlietfl Has wrote an excellent answer for that. In case you are not aware of promises you can go ahead with for looping on the image URLs and adding a new image tag on each loop specifying the `onload` callback and `src`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object refers to a single `<img src=""/>` tag. Changing the src that way will not give time for the images to load. It would be better to create 3 image objects and wait for all 3 onload functions to get called before doing what you need to do.